# Linear gradient percentages vs pixels

Tags: css, gradient, percentage

I have two examples, both of which to my knowledge should be identical.

The percentages are calculated based on the width which is `960px;`

Here's the pixel version, which seems to work great.

```
.pixel {
    background-color: #111111;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 40px, #444 20px );
    background-size: 60px, 950px;
    background-position: 10px, 10px;
}
```

However the identical percentage based gradient doesn't work:

```
.percentage {
    background-color: #111111;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 4.1666%, #444 2.08333%);
    background-size: 6.25%, 98.95833%;
    background-position: 1.04167%, 1.04167%;
}
```

I want to use percentages so that this gradient is fluid when the container shrinks size.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/shannonhochkins/A3Z2L/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the percentages inside the `linear-gradient` are expected to add up to 100%.

Your second example is saying "within the 6.25% (60px) of the `background-size`, the first 4.1666% is transparent and the next 2.08333% is gray", but you're not specifying what color the remaining 93.75007% of that 60px should be. (It looks like it just uses the last color for the remaining space, so within your 60-px background-size, you've got 4.1666% transparent and the remaining 95.8334% gray.)

Given that your proportions are 66%/33% in your first example, your second example should be using `linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 66.6667%, #444 33.3333%)`.

Comment: also, unrelated, however is there a version of this gradient I should make for '-webkit-, -o-, -moz-' ?

Comment: Both the 20px value in the first case, and the 33.3% in the second, are useless. Any stop value that is lower than the previous one will be set to that. So, in the first case, any value between 0px and 40px will get a change from transparent to red at 40px. And any value higher than 40px will give soft transitions. For instance, setting the second stop to 42px will give transition during 2 px. And the same goes for the percentages

Answer (score 1):

The percentage in background-image isn't based on 1000px. It's based on the background size. In this case you want 66.6% of 60px.

```
.percentage {
background-color: #111111;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 66.6666%, #444 2.08333%);
background-size: 6.25%, 98.95833%;
background-position: 1.04167%, 1.04167%;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! Although your second width of the `linear gradient` is incorrect, it should be 3.333 recurring :)

Comment: @ShannonHochkins You mean 33.3333. I changed the height values in Chrome and it made no difference. For all I know it does in real life though.

Comment: I did say recurring, but anyway, the second parameter is the horizontal spacing just so you know